# How to implement invFunc in reduceByKeyAndWindow() for specific use case

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to process stream of files. multiple files arrive in a batch and spark process data from all the files.
My use is to get the sum of each record over the files coming into subsequent batches. For example:

- key: key_1 value: 10 --> batch1
- key: key_1 value: 05 --> batch1
- key: key_1 value: 19 --> batch2
- key: key_1 value: 11 --> batch3
- key: key_1 value: 10 --> batch4

I need output something like following:

- After processing 1st batch I need output as => key: key_1 val: 15
- After processing 2nd batch I need output as => key: key_1 val: 34
- After processing 3rd batch I need output as => key: key_1 val: 45
- After processing 4th batch I need output as => key: key_1 val: 55
- After processing 5th batch I need output as => key: key_1 val: 55

My spark piece of code with **reduceByKeyAndWindow()** is as following:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> grpSumRDD = sumRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow(GET_GRP_SUM, Durations.minutes(2*batchInterval), Durations.minutes(batchInterval));

private static final Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary> GET_GRP_SUM = new Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Summary call(Summary s1, Summary s2) throws Exception {
        try {

            Summary s = new Summary();

            long grpCnt = s1.getDelta() + s2.getDelta();
            s.setDeltaSum(grpCnt);

            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" ==== error in CKT_GRP_SUM ==== :"+e);
            return new Summary();
        }
    }
```

};

The output which i am getting from above implentation is as following:

- After processing 1st batch I am getting output => key: key_1 value: 15
- After processing 2nd batch I am getting output => key: key_1 value: 34
- After processing 3rd batch I am getting output => key: key_1 value: 30
- After processing 4th batch I am getting output => key: key_1 value: 21
- After processing 5th batch I am getting output => key: key_1 value: 10

Based on the output of reduceByKeyAndWindow() it seems that it is calculating the aggregation of previous batch data and current batch data.
But my requirement is to do the aggregation on previous batch's aggregated data and current batch data. so that as per examaple above 
it should output as [(((15)+19)+11)+10 = 55] at the end of 4th and 5th batch.

I read about **reduceByKeyAndWindow()** with **invFunc** can be implemented to get the expected output. I tried to implement it similar to **GET_GRP_SUM** but it not giving me expected result. Any help with the correct implemention to get the desired output will be appreciated.

I am using java 1.8.45 and spark version 1.4.1 with hadoop version 2.7.1 .

My Implemention on invFunc with reduceByKeyAndWindow()

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> grpSumRDD = sumRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow(GET_GRP_SUM, INV_GET_GRP_SUM, Durations.minutes(2*batchInterval), Durations.minutes(batchInterval));

private static final Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary> INV_GET_GRP_SUM = new Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Summary call(Summary s1, Summary s2) throws Exception {
        try {

            Summary s = new Summary();

            long grpCnt = s1.getDelta() + s2.getDelta();
            s.setDeltaSum(grpCnt);

            return s;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" ==== error in INV_GET_GRP_SUM ==== :"+e);
            return new Summary();
        }
    }
};
```

I have implemented my invFunc like above, this is not giving me expected output. What I analyzed here is that s1 and s2 giving me previous batches aggregated value thought I am not very sure.

I tried to change my invFunc implementation like following:

```
private static final Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary> INV_GET_GRP_SUM = new Function2<Summary, Summary, Summary>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Summary call(Summary s1, Summary s2) throws Exception {
        try {

            return s1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" ==== error in INV_GET_GRP_SUM ==== :"+e);
            return new Summary();
        }
    }
};
```

This implementation is giving me expected output. But the problem which I face is that reduceByKeyAndWindow() with invFunc not removing older keys automatically. I gone through with few more posts and I found that I need to write my own filter function which will delete older keys with 0 values (no values).

Again I am not sure how to write filter function to delete older keys with 0 value(no value) because I am not having concrete understanding of what s1 and s2 returning into INV_GET_GRP_SUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using UpdateStateByKey

Have you checked out `updateStateByKey()` from the Streaming API? It allows you to maintain state for key-value pairs between batch intervals, constantly updating each key with new information (values) associated with it. This works well for your use case, since the previous state of data will contain the aggregated sum for each key up until the newest state. More information on this function can found in its usage [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams) and in an example [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html).

One note about the function is that it requires checkpointing to be enabled so that state can be saved on each iteration.

(EDIT:)

#### Using ReduceByKeyAndWindow

With respect to using `reduceKeyAndWindow()`, the second argument to the `call()` method for your normal *func* and your *invFunc* are the new elements being added and the old elements being subtracted respectively. Essentially, you are implementing this windowed reduce by adding elements on from the new slice of time (which you are doing with `GET_GRP_SUM`) and subtracting elements from the old time slice (which you are not doing with `INV_GET_GRP_SUM`). Notice that in your first attempt, you are re-adding the old values back to the currently-in-window values and in your second attempt, you are ignoring the values shifting out of the window.

To subtract the old values from the elements shifting out of the window, you probably want to have `INV_GET_GRP_SUM` have logic similar to the below (and can find a similar correct implementation [here](https://github.com/holdenk/learning-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/java/logs/LogAnalyzerWindowed.java#L48)):

```
public Summary call(Summary s1, Summary s2) throws Exception {
    try {

        long grpCnt = s1.getDelta() - s2.getDelta();
        s.setDeltaSum(grpCnt);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(" ==== error in INV_GET_GRP_SUM ==== :"+e);
        return new Summary();
    }
}
```

To your other question, there does seem to be a way to filter out expired keys and, as you mentioned, it does involve writing a filter function. As you can see from the [API](http://bit.ly/1MBSIYw), this filter function takes in your key-value pair and returns a boolean that will be set to true (if you want to keep the pair) or false (if you want to remove the pair). In this case, since you want to remove your pair once the value hits zero, you could do something like:

```
private static final Function<scala.Tuple2<String, Summary>, Boolean> FILTER_EXPIRED = new Function<scala.Tuple2<String, Summary>, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(scala.Tuple2<String, Summary> s) { 
        return s.productElement(1) > 0; 
    }
}
```

Then you can pass this into your `reduceByKeyAndWindow()` function (note that you should pass in the partition parameter here to settle how many partitions the RDD's from your `DStream` will use):

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> grpSumRDD = sumRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow(GET_GRP_SUM, INV_GET_GRP_SUM, Durations.minutes(2*batchInterval), Durations.minutes(batchInterval), partitions, FILTER_EXPIRED);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan for your quick reply. One thing I need to mention is that One batch has around 100K-500K records to process and 
keys over the batches keep on changing with time. In this case if I use updateStateByKey(), cache which stores record keys will keep on increasing while older record will never be repeated after 2-3 batches. Example scenario which I explained in my question is just to understand the use case. That's why I decided to use reduceByKeyAndWindow() So that Spark will look for same record(with same key) into previous and current batch by having a window of 2-3 batches.

Comment: You can actually configure your keys to be removed with `updateStateByKey()` after some period of time (if you're not seeing any new values for a key). However, if you are set on using `reduceByKeyAndWindow()`, can you add the code you are trying run with with the invFunc?

Comment: Hi Rohan, I have edited my question with implementation of invFunc. Please have a look and let me know if you can help me with filtering older key values.

Comment: Hey @user3478678, I added some information for your use case with `reduceByKeyAndWindow()`. Hopefully that helps!